# How to roll back a Jenkins build to a previous stable one

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job which creates build from GIT and deploys code to a instance via using Ansible. For every build Jenkins give it a number for ex. Build #1, Build #2 and so on. Suppose, Build #2 got executed and code is updated on instance and I found a major glitch after the deployment and I want to revert it to Build #1 again. So, is there a way this can be done via Jenkins or via GIT to revert the changes to last stable one. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I do not remember whether Jenkins itself has rebuild menu item or with Rebuild Plugin. I do enter rebuild. And it just re build the exisitig build with necessary parameters. So in your case it will the proper git version. Once the build complete the right artifacts will be populated.